# Find comma in the parameters of a function using regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to find the occurrence of a chain call functions, but must include the case where there is more than one parameter passed as (programming in java):

**Tower.getType(i,j).initialPrice(f,g);**

**Tower.getType().initialPrice();**

So far only managed to make the regex when there is only one parameter or no one:

**[\w]+([.]+[\w]+[(]+[\w]*+[)]){2,}+[;]**

Like:

**Tower.getType().initialPrice();**

**object.function().function2().function3().function4().function5();**

I trying this, but its not working:

**[\w] + ([\.] + [\w] + [(] + [\w]* + ([\,] + [\w])* + [)]) {2,} + [;]**

My code:

```
public static void checksMessageChain (String s) {        
if (s!=null && s.matches("[\\w]+([\\.]+[\\w]+[(]+[\\w]*+[)]){2,}+[;]")) {
    System.out.println("\nIts Message Chain for "+s+"\n");
    splitMessageChain(s); // {0,} equivale a *
} else if (s!=null && s.matches("[\\w] + ([\\.] + [\\w] + [(] + [\\w]* + ([\\,] + [\\w])* + [)]) {2,} + [;]")) {
    System.out.println("\nIts Message Chain for "+s+"\n");
    splitMessageChain(s);
} else {
    System.out.println("\nIts not Message Chain for "+s+"\n");   
} }
```

Comment: can you give some sample input/output?

Comment: You had a problem so decided to use regexes - now you have two problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with specifying the parameters and just use this :

```
\\w+(?:\\.\\w+\\([^)]*\\)){2,};
```

Note that this will fail if one String parameter contains a closing parenthesis, and it doesn't handle multi-line expressions.
As is usual for such a complex language, you'd better use a specialized parser. I have never used one, but a quick search reveals [javaparser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser) available on Github.

You can try it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sN7rL8/4).

Comment: I use AST parser, but after that i need check if the function its message chain or not... and the regex101 its very usefull! Thanks!

Comment: Wait, you need at least two method calls chained, right? I forgot to take this into account, I've updated my regex and regex101 test. And you're welcome !

Comment: Thanks for the help! (:

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to do this using Regex: you will get an headache and a program that will not cover all possible cases.

Just use JavaParser: it is opensource, it is lightweight, it does not have dependencies.

You can either parse the whole Java file and then navigate the Abstract Syntax Tree to find your function calls or you can directly parse the single expression you are interested into, if you have already identified that piece of source code.

In the first case you want to call [parse](http://static.javadoc.io/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core/3.0.0-alpha.6/com/github/javaparser/JavaParser.html#parse-java.lang.String-), otherwise [parseExpression](http://static.javadoc.io/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core/3.0.0-alpha.6/com/github/javaparser/JavaParser.html#parseExpression-java.lang.String-)

Once you get your [MethodCallExpr](http://static.javadoc.io/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core/3.0.0-alpha.6/com/github/javaparser/ast/expr/MethodCallExpr.html) if its parent is another MethodCallExpr then you have chained calls.

Disclaimer: I am a JavaParser contributor